# How to assign short xml to string using VBA in rdlc report

Tags: c#, vba, rdlc

I am working on an in which I am working on rdlc report where I need to assign XML to string but it's giving me an error stated below

> because the parent element's content model is text-only

Here is my code

```
Dim AllLoc as String
      Dim AllDept as String

      Function SetVal()

      AllLoc = "=<root Selected="all"/>"
      AllDept = "=<root Selected="all"/>"

      End Function
```

Calling this function

```
 <QueryParameter Name="@AllLoc">
            <Value>=Code.SetVal()</Value>
          </QueryParameter>




 Function SetLocationValue(locationId as Integer, allLoc as Integer) As String
        
        if allLoc = 1 Then
            return  "&lt;root Selected="all"/&gt;"
        else
             Dim val As String =  "&lt;root Selected="list"&gt;&lt;id&gt; CStr(locationId)  &lt;/id&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"
             return val
        End if

      End Function

      Function SetDepartmentValue(deptId as Integer, allDept as Integer) As String
            if allDept = 1 Then
                     return  "&lt;root Selected="all"/&gt;"
            else
                   Dim val As String =  "&lt;root Selected="list"&gt;&lt;id&gt; CStr(deptId)  &lt;/id&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"
                   return val
            End if

      End Function
```

Comment: Following https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98691/the-element-cannot-contain-child-element-because-the-parent-elements-content-mo try `AllLoc = "=&ltroot Selected="all"/&gt"` etc